# How to make dynamic link in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have:

```
<b-dropdown text="Select Factory" block variant="primary" class="m-2" menu-class="w-100">
<b-dropdown-item @click="selectedFactory='China'">China</b-dropdown-item>
<b-dropdown-item @click="selectedFactory='Europe'">Europe</b-dropdown-item>   
</b-dropdown>
    
<b-dropdown text="Select Toy" block variant="primary" class="m-2" menu-class="w-100">
<b-dropdown-item @click="selectedToy='Marvel'">Marvel</b-dropdown-item>
<b-dropdown-item @click="selectedToy='Toy Story'">Toy Story</b-dropdown-item>   
</b-dropdown>
```

How can I make this line of code work, such that the source link is dynamic? Currently it does work with the dropdown selection when embeded into an iframe. I am guessing probably something to do with the compute function, am not very sure

```
export default {

el: '#apps',
  data () {
     return {
       
        source:'http://127.0.0.1:5503/src/html/`{{this.selectedFactory}}`_{{this.selectedToy}}.html',
        selectedFactory: '',
        selectedToy:'',
     }
  }, 
  computed:{

  }
    
   
}
```

Comment: Source shouldn’t be defined in data but should be a computed property instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should use `<router-link>` inside `<b-dropdown-item>`, like this:

```
<b-dropdown-item><router-link :to="some_url">China</router-link></b-dropdown-item>
...
data() {
  return {
    some_url: '',
  };
},
```

or:

```
computed: {    some_url() { return 'foo' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make use of v-bind directive in your template, like so:

`<a v-bind:href="source">{{selectedFactory + selectedToy}}</a>`

As for your data property, I believe you can use normal string concatenation to make your dynamic url:

```
data () {
     return {
        source:'http://127.0.0.1:5503/src/html/' + this.selectedFactory + '_' + this.selectedToy + '.html',
        selectedFactory: '',
        selectedToy:'',
     }
  }
```

The {{}} double curly brace syntax is for use in your html code of your vue app. Hope it helps!

Comment: This won't work because `this.selectedFactory` will not yet exist in `data()` (resulting in a compile error). Also, `data()` is not reactive, so updates to `selectedFactory` wouldn't be reflected in `source`.

Comment: @bdela I just tried your method and it cannot work. not very sure why. pardon me because i am new to vue.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer:

```
   export default {
    el: '#apps',
      data () {
         return {
            selectedFactory: '',
            selectedToy:'',
         }
      }, 
      computed:{
         source: function(){ return'http://127.0.0.1:5503/src/html/'+this.selectedFactory+'_'+this.selectedToy+'.html',
}

      }
        
       
    }
```